# C language - returning two dimensional array of chars

Tags: c, scope, implicit-conversion

I am trying to return a two dimensional array but it doesn't really assign to the str variable. Can someone navigate me to what am I doing wrong?

```
int main()
    {
        char** str = OpenFile();

    //reverseString(str);

   return 0;
}

char** OpenFile() {

    char line[HEIGHT][LENGTH];
    char *fname = "test.txt";
    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
    while(fgets(line[i], LENGTH, fptr))
    {
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    return line;
}
```

Comment: `line` is a local variable of `OpenFile`. You cannot return a local variable. It is "gone" once the function returns.

Comment: One possible solution is using `static char line[HEIGHT][LENGTH];´

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   at the very least, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files

Answer (score 3):

```
char line[HEIGHT][LENGTH];
```

Your array variable line[][] is declared as a local variable within the OpenFile() function. Therefore it goes out of scope as soon as OpenFile() finishes execution. You can either declare line[][] as global or you may pass it to your function as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Returning pointer to a local object with the automatic storage duration from a function makes the pointer invalid because the local object will not be alive after exiting the function.

And secondly the type `char**`, the return type of the showed function, and the type `char ( * )[LENGTH]`, the type of the returned expression, are different.

You could dynamically allocate within the function an array of arrays and return it.

For example

```
char (* OpenFile() )[LENGTH] {

    char ( * line )[LENGTH] = malloc( HEIGHT * sizeof( char[LENGTH] ) );
    //...

    retirn line;
}
```

This approach is flexible because you can reallocate the array within the function if it is required.

Or you could define the array with the storage specifier static like

```
char (* OpenFile() )[LENGTH] {

    static char line[JEIGHT][LENGTH];
    //...

    retirn line;
}
```

Pay attention to that this statement

```
line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
```

is unsafe. It is not necessary that the function fgets appends the entered string with the new line character `'\n'`. A safe approach is the following

```
line[i][ strcspn( line[i], "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```